# 2 foreign keys linked sender and receiver in messages

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, schema, foreign-key-relationship

So I have a client table with a `clientid` and a `serviceprovider` table with `spid`. I want to link them in my table `messages` that has a sender and receiver column. but it doesnt seem to work if I reference both clientid and spid to sender and to reciever.

What is a good way to reference them?

[image]

Comment: you should have sender and receiver  as foreign key of client id if both are alway client

Comment: just to clarify: both clients and service providers can be senders and receivers of messages?

Comment: yes, my plan is to make them both as senders and recievers

Comment: Foreign keys cannot handle this situation. Either you cannot use foreign keys or you need to change your table structure, so that all clients and service providers are stored in a single table.

Comment: I did consider making 'clients' and 'serviceproviders' to be in one table but their columns are too different. So there are no other work arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If senders and receivers of a message can be in either clients on service providers tables, then you cannot use foreign keys to ensure referential integrity. A single foreign key can only point to one table.

If you insist on having separate clients and service providers tables, then you can use triggers instead of foreign keys to ensure referential integrity.

You would define before insert / update triggers on the messages table that would check if the sender / receiver exists in any of the 2 tables and raise an error message if it does not. You also have to make sure that no client has the same id as a service provider, otherwise you will not be able to distinguish between them.

You would define before update / delete triggers on the clients / service providers tables to make sure you do not modify an id that has related messages (or update the id in the messages table as well).

The other alternative is to change your database structure and move the clients and service providers into a single table. In this case you can use foreign keys to ensure referential integrity of your data.

Comment: The clients and service providers have different id patterns so i think I do not have any problem with service providers and clients id

Comment: So i have big question... How do I refer to other tables using triggers?
`CREATE TRIGGER check_if_exist
BEFORE INSERT
ON messages
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.sender = (bxb.client.clientno) OR NEW.sender = (bxb.serviceprovider.spid) OR NEW.receiver = (bxb.client.clientno) OR NEW.sender = (bxb.serviceprovider.spid);` this doesnt seem to work

Comment: Pls ask follow-up questions in their own separate question, not in a comment.

Comment: I'm sorry. Thank you for clarifying :>